# horizontalSilder (PyQt5) : Event depending of position | Start position depending of process

Tags: python, slider, pyqt5

I have some questions about horizontalSlider on PyQt5.
I would like to have my slider doing action depending if position is 1 or 0. So 1 startprocess and 0 stop process.
here is my code :

```py
  self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(Form)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 50, 51, 41))
        self.horizontalSlider.setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal { \n"
"    background-color: #bdc3c7;\n"
"    border: 0px solid #424242; \n"
"    height: 18px; \n"
"    border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::handle:horizontal { \n"
"    background-color: #7f8c8d; \n"
"    border: 2px solid #7f8c8d; \n"
"    width: 16px; \n"
"    height: 20px; \n"
"    line-height: 20px; \n"
"    margin-top: -5px; \n"
"    margin-bottom: -5px; \n"
"    border-radius: 10px; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover { \n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::sub-page:Horizontal { \n"
"background-color: #27ae60;\n"
"border : 0px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::add-page:Horizontal {\n"
" background-color: #e74c3c;\n"
"border : 0px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
" }")
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(1)
        self.horizontalSlider.setPageStep(1)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setInvertedAppearance(False)
        self.horizontalSlider.setInvertedControls(False)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.NoTicks)
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.call_deadlineslave)

# There is more code between

def press_key_event(self, event):
        if event.key()==Qt.Key_Right:
            self.horizontalSlider.setValue(self.horizontalSlider.value()+1)
        elif event.key()==Qt.Key_Left:
            self.horizontalSlider.setValue(self.horizontalSlider.value()-1)
        else :
            QtWidgets.press_key_event(self, event)

    def call_deadlineslave(self):
        commands.enable_deadlineslave()
```

and the second things is the start position. Could I make my slider start right if slave enable and left if slave disable ? Like if dealineslave.exe run the slider start right ?

Thanks a lot,
Best,
Pixidream

Answer (score 0):

To make your slider trigger different behaviour depending on it's position, you can use the `.valueChanged` signal — which you already have connected here:

```
self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.call_deadlineslave)
```

The receiving slot `self.call_deadlineslave` will receive the new value, e.g.

```
def call_deadlineslave(self, value):
    if value == 1:
        commands.enable_deadlineslave()
    else:
        commands.disable_deadlineslave()
```

To determine the start value at startup, you can use `.setValue` when creating the slider. It will update before being visible, so will appear to start in whatever position you like.

```
self.horizontalSlider.setValue(1)
```

Or

```
self.horizontalSlider.setValue(0)
```

One other note, you set the value +1 here:

```
self.horizontalSlider.setValue(self.horizontalSlider.value()+1)
```

...but the slider is limited to 0..1, so you may as well just set:

```
self.horizontalSlider.setValue(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mfitzp for your anwser !
I resolve my problem with the following code :

```py
self.horizontalSlider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalSlider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 30, 51, 41))
        self.horizontalSlider.setStyleSheet("QSlider::groove:horizontal { \n"
"    background-color: #bdc3c7;\n"
"    border: 0px solid #424242; \n"
"    height: 18px; \n"
"    border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::handle:horizontal { \n"
"    background-color: #7f8c8d; \n"
"    border: 2px solid #7f8c8d; \n"
"    width: 16px; \n"
"    height: 20px; \n"
"    line-height: 20px; \n"
"    margin-top: -5px; \n"
"    margin-bottom: -5px; \n"
"    border-radius: 10px; \n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::handle:horizontal:hover { \n"
"    border-radius: 10px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::sub-page:Horizontal { \n"
"background-color: #27ae60;\n"
"border : 0px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
"}\n"
"\n"
"QSlider::add-page:Horizontal {\n"
" background-color: #e74c3c;\n"
"border : 0px solid;\n"
"border-radius: 8px;\n"
" }")
        self.horizontalSlider.setMaximum(1)
        self.horizontalSlider.setPageStep(1)
        self.horizontalSlider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.horizontalSlider.setInvertedAppearance(False)
        self.horizontalSlider.setInvertedControls(False)
        self.horizontalSlider.setTickPosition(QtWidgets.QSlider.NoTicks)
        self.horizontalSlider.setObjectName("horizontalSlider")
        self.horizontalSlider.valueChanged.connect(self.change_value)
```

```py
    def change_value(self, value):
        if value == 1:
            self.call_deadlineslave()
        else:
            self.kill_deadlineslave()
```